# Should I create a parent page with no content?

Tags: search, seo

From an SEO perspective, should I ever have a blank parent page on my website?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit out of the scope of this site, but according to Google, creating any URL without content would not be beneficial for SEO. It would likely work better SEO-wise to create a custom post type that has no archive, so you have the parent slug you're wanting in the URL without actually having an accessible URL at that parent level.